# facebook graph api get_started button issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

At a facebook page, where i am not an admin, subscribed to my facebook app, which is a chatbot. Altough the chatbot functioning already, i cannot setup the get_started button with the following call:

https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/messenger_profile?access_token=theaccesstoken

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
  }
}
```

it works for the pages i am admin of, but for this page i get the following response:

```
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "44323423423423"
    }
}
```

the access token has the followiing permissions for the page:
email, manage_pages, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, pages_messaging, public_profile
the token did not expire

Can some explain please what should be done differently?

[UPDATE]
The problem occured because the user was not a page admin, just an editor.

Comment: _“Can some explain plase what should be done differently?”_ - become an actual page admin, I guess? What role do you currently have on the page?

Comment: i do not have any role and I won't be able to be the page admin for all pages which want to use my app. 
The page admin connected my app to his page, so he has the admin rights. It's works like the manychat, any page admin can give permission to his page for the app to answer questions automatically. the app answers all the questions already, the issue is with the get started button

Comment: Sounds like they might not actually have a sufficient “tasks” level assigned on the page then. The available choices are MANAGE, CREATE_CONTENT, MODERATE, ADVERTISE and ANALYZE - not sure which one(s) are needed, but I suspect it might be full MANAGE. So go check with them which one they actually have.

Comment: the problam occured bacause the user was not a page admin just an editor.